# C++ substring on pointers

Tags: c++, string, performance, memory

Is it possible in C++ to create a substring as pointers to the same memory as the original string?

Lets say I've got a string `s = "just testing"` and a function `f`. I want function f to return a constant string object (user can not change it), which will be a substring of `s` and I want `f` to create this substring the most efficient way.

The only idea I've got is to return a pair of pointers - on the beginning and end of the substring, but I would love to give the end user the "feeling" that `f` returns an object and he can print it, iterate over it etc.

Is it possible in C++?

Comment: See http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/libs/utility/doc/html/string_ref.html

Comment: ...and [`QStringRef`](http://harmattan-dev.nokia.com/docs/library/html/qt4/qstringref.html) in Qt

Comment: Yes, of course this is possible, but it's better to have safer facility then simply 2 raw pointers. I.e. you need a class that would provide this functionality and abstract the client from the exact way how it is implemented.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any reason (performance, flexibility etc) when I should use `QStringRef` instead of boost one if I'm not using QT?

Comment: If you are not using Qt, then there is no point to impose such a heavyweight dependency as `QtCore` on your project just to get this functionality. Stick with Boost, I doubt that you can run into performance bottleneck with any of them.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, it's possible.

You should write your own class as a wrapper around beginning and ending of the sub-string.

This code is not complete, but show the direction.

```
class string_ref
{
    std::string::iterator b, e; // begin and end
public:
    string_ref(std::string::iterator b, std::string::iterator e) : b(b), e(e){}

    std::string to_string() const {
        return std::string(b, e);
    }

    std::string::iterator begin() const {
        return b;
    }

    std::string::iterator end() const {
        return e;
    }
    // ... Code to complete this class ... //
};

std::ostream &operator<<(std::ostream &out, const string_ref &str) {
    // out << str.to_string();
    for (std::string::iterator i = str.begin(); i != str.end(); i++) cout << *i;
    return out;
}

int main() {
    std::string s = "Hello";
    string_ref sr(s.begin(), next(s.begin(),3)); // pick first 3 charaters
    cout << sr << endl;                          // print it by cout
}
```

You can iterate and print it simply.

Comment: You still do a copy by `to_string()`. What author was asking for is to have a read-only _"view"_ of the portion of the original string. In other words, no additional memory allocations should happen. Therefore, this implementation is sort of naive.

Comment: @Haroogan: `to_string()` is mandatory when you want use `string_ref` beside other STLs. Storing the beginning and ending iterators are the "_view_". And it has not additional memory allocation, would you show it to me? (This code is based on famous boost and Qt approaches to store sub-strings)

Comment: I already told you that one introduces additional memory allocation when using `to_string()`. Yes, it is indeed needed to operate with standard library code. However, for example, the implementation of `operator<<` in your case does this unnecessary memory allocation by employing `to_string()`, rather than feeding the stream with characters directly.

Comment: I agree, It's not the best, but the main goal of the code is just show to wrap those couple of iterators and how to overload `operator<<` which works with `string_ref`. Also, that's temporary allocated memory during operations not permanently during existence of `string_ref`.

Comment: I added a piece of code that shows we can avoid using `to_string` in `operator<<`.